# To take objects from array having id in all objects which is stored in array as key value pair in every objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 6 typescript.As I am new to this I want some help I have an array of objects as below :

```
[{"roomCode":"BR-017","roomDescription":"Raum 017 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"PC-SCH","SetupDescription":"PC Schulung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"SONDER","SetupDescription":"Sonderbestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":10,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"STEHT","SetupDescription":"Stehtische","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":40,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":8,"maxQuantity":18,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"M2","FeatrureDescription":"Fläche in m²","minQuantity":100,"maxQuantity":100,"uomCode":"M2"},{"FeatureId":"PC","FeatrureDescription":"PC","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":10,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"TEL","FeatrureDescription":"Telefon","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"WLAN","FeatrureDescription":"WLAN","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":15,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-024","roomDescription":"Raum 024 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"BUFFET","SetupDescription":"Buffet","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"KINO","SetupDescription":"Kinobestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"KONF","SetupDescription":"Konferenzbestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":14,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"LEER","SetupDescription":"ohne Bestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":17,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"PC-SCH","SetupDescription":"PC Schulung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":33,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"S-KONF","SetupDescription":"schmale Konferenzbestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":33,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"SONDER","SetupDescription":"Sonderbestuhlung","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":13,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"STEHT","SetupDescription":"Stehtische","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":22,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"TISCHK","SetupDescription":"Tischkreis","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":22,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"8SWI","FeatrureDescription":"8er Switch","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":111,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"BEAM","FeatrureDescription":"Beamer","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"BILDS","FeatrureDescription":"Bildschirm","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"FLIP","FeatrureDescription":"Flipchart","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"M2","FeatrureDescription":"Fläche in m²","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"M2"},{"FeatureId":"MOD","FeatrureDescription":"Moderationskoffer","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"PC","FeatrureDescription":"PC","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"PINN","FeatrureDescription":"Pinnwand","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"ROLLSTUH","FeatrureDescription":"Zugang für Rollstühle","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"TEKO","FeatrureDescription":"Telefonkonferenz-Anlage","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"TEL","FeatrureDescription":"Telefon","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"TONKL","FeatrureDescription":"Tonanlage klein (Handmikrofon)","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"VK","FeatrureDescription":"Videokonferenzanlage","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"WLAN","FeatrureDescription":"WLAN","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":11,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-025","roomDescription":"Raum 025 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-101","roomDescription":"Raum 101 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-102","roomDescription":"Raum 102 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":10,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-103","roomDescription":"Raum 103 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-104","roomDescription":"Raum 104 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-105","roomDescription":"Raum 105 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-106","roomDescription":"Raum 106 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-107","roomDescription":"Raum 107 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-108","roomDescription":"Raum 108 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-109","roomDescription":"Raum 109 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"TISCHB","SetupDescription":"Tischblock/blöcke","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":8,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-114","roomDescription":"Raum 114 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":3,"maxQuantity":18,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"BEAM","FeatrureDescription":"Beamer","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"FLIP","FeatrureDescription":"Flipchart","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":2,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"PINN","FeatrureDescription":"Pinnwand","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":3,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-116","roomDescription":"Raum 116 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"PC-SCH","SetupDescription":"PC Schulung","minQuantity":2,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"PC","FeatrureDescription":"PC","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-118","roomDescription":"Raum 118 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"PC-SCH","SetupDescription":"PC Schulung","minQuantity":2,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"PC","FeatrureDescription":"PC","minQuantity":1,"maxQuantity":12,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-119","roomDescription":"Raum 119 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":4,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"BEAM","FeatrureDescription":"Beamer","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"FLIP","FeatrureDescription":"Flipchart","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":2,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"PINN","FeatrureDescription":"Pinnwand","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":3,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-120","roomDescription":"Raum 120 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":4,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[{"FeatureId":"BEAM","FeatrureDescription":"Beamer","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":1,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"FLIP","FeatrureDescription":"Flipchart","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":2,"uomCode":"STK"},{"FeatureId":"PINN","FeatrureDescription":"Pinnwand","minQuantity":0,"maxQuantity":3,"uomCode":"STK"}]},{"roomCode":"BR-121","roomDescription":"Raum 121 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":24,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":24,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-122","roomDescription":"Raum 122 Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":9,"maxQuantity":20,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]},{"roomCode":"BR-K45","roomDescription":"Kombi R024+R025  Brühl","setups":[{"SetupId":"KINO","SetupDescription":"Kinobestuhlung","minQuantity":21,"maxQuantity":42,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"STUHLK","SetupDescription":"Stuhlkreis","minQuantity":21,"maxQuantity":42,"uomCode":"PRS"},{"SetupId":"U-FORM","SetupDescription":"U-Form","minQuantity":21,"maxQuantity":42,"uomCode":"PRS"}],"features":[]}]
```

I want to take out only those objects of features array which is common in all room objects array. For example here featured with WLAN is common for all room objects so my result would be featured:

`[0:{featureId: WLAN featureDesc: wifilan}]`

and if there are multiple objects in common the array of objects will increase accordingly and if there are no objects in common then the array will be empty.
Thanks in advance :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx6NZ.png)

Comment: Hi, [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please include valid JSON, and format it as code instead of posting an image. That allows others to copy / paste the code in order to test their solution. You can get valid JSON by calling `JSON.stringify` on your array

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Some of your rooms have an empty feature array, so by definition there cannot be any features that are contained in every room

Comment: Yes but if there are some feature then i have to take that objects

Comment: You can delete the objects having feature as empty for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to break down the problem into steps.

In the code below, I've done this in 3 steps:

1. Extract all of the features into an array
2. Remove any duplicate features
3. Filter the features so that we're only left with the common ones.

In the code below, I've only included the first 2 rooms from your data. You should be able to click `Run code snippet` to see the result.

```js
let data = [{
    "roomCode": "BR-017",
    "roomDescription": "Raum 017 Brühl",
    "setups": [{
        "SetupId": "PC-SCH",
        "SetupDescription": "PC Schulung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 20,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "SONDER",
        "SetupDescription": "Sonderbestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 10,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "STEHT",
        "SetupDescription": "Stehtische",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 40,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "U-FORM",
        "SetupDescription": "U-Form",
        "minQuantity": 8,
        "maxQuantity": 18,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }],
    "features": [{
        "FeatureId": "M2",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Fläche in m²",
        "minQuantity": 100,
        "maxQuantity": 100,
        "uomCode": "M2"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "PC",
        "FeatrureDescription": "PC",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 10,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "TEL",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Telefon",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 12,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "WLAN",
        "FeatrureDescription": "WLAN",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 15,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }]
}, {
    "roomCode": "BR-024",
    "roomDescription": "Raum 024 Brühl",
    "setups": [{
        "SetupId": "BUFFET",
        "SetupDescription": "Buffet",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 12,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "KINO",
        "SetupDescription": "Kinobestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 12,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "KONF",
        "SetupDescription": "Konferenzbestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 14,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "LEER",
        "SetupDescription": "ohne Bestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 17,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "PC-SCH",
        "SetupDescription": "PC Schulung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 33,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "S-KONF",
        "SetupDescription": "schmale Konferenzbestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 33,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "SONDER",
        "SetupDescription": "Sonderbestuhlung",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 13,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "STEHT",
        "SetupDescription": "Stehtische",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 12,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "STUHLK",
        "SetupDescription": "Stuhlkreis",
        "minQuantity": 9,
        "maxQuantity": 20,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "TISCHB",
        "SetupDescription": "Tischblock/blöcke",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 22,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "TISCHK",
        "SetupDescription": "Tischkreis",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "maxQuantity": 22,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }, {
        "SetupId": "U-FORM",
        "SetupDescription": "U-Form",
        "minQuantity": 9,
        "maxQuantity": 20,
        "uomCode": "PRS"
    }],
    "features": [{
        "FeatureId": "8SWI",
        "FeatrureDescription": "8er Switch",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 111,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "BEAM",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Beamer",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "BILDS",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Bildschirm",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 1,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "FLIP",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Flipchart",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "M2",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Fläche in m²",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "M2"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "MOD",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Moderationskoffer",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "PC",
        "FeatrureDescription": "PC",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "PINN",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Pinnwand",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "ROLLSTUH",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Zugang für Rollstühle",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "TEKO",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Telefonkonferenz-Anlage",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "TEL",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Telefon",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 1,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "TONKL",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Tonanlage klein (Handmikrofon)",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 1,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "VK",
        "FeatrureDescription": "Videokonferenzanlage",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }, {
        "FeatureId": "WLAN",
        "FeatrureDescription": "WLAN",
        "minQuantity": 0,
        "maxQuantity": 11,
        "uomCode": "STK"
    }]
}]


// Create an array containing all the features
let features = data.reduce((features, room) => [...features, ...room.features], []);

// Remove any duplicates
features = features.filter((feat, idx) => features.findIndex(f => f.FeatureId === feat.FeatureId) === idx)

// Remove any that aren't in every room
features = features.filter(feature => data.every(room => room.features.find(f => f.FeatureId === feature.FeatureId)))

// Log the result
console.log(features);
```